# Why are these loops different?

Tags: javascript

I was working on my site at work, when I encountered  something strange, I'm fetching data from a database via ajax, and then I uses some loops to update the data in a table. Here is my first attempt at the loop

```
for(var id in data){
    for(var key in data[id])
        for(var e in document.getElementsByName(key+id))
            e.innerHTML = data[id][key] !== null ? data[id][key] : "";
```

I expected that to work without a problem, but it doesn't. None of the fields in the table gets updated, and I have no idea why. Then I decided to test with something more traditional, and ended up with this.

```
for(var id in data){
    for(var key in data[id]){
        var temp = document.getElementsByName(key+id);
        for(var i=0; i<temp.length; i++)
            temp[i].innerHTML = data[id][key] !== null ? data[id][key] : "";
    }
```

That worked prefect, but I don't understand why, since from what I can see, the loops should do the same thing. So I wonder, why are they different, and how can I fix it. I like consistencies in my codes, and don't want to use the `for(var i=0; i<temp.length; i++)` since I used the other types of loops earlier.

Comment: Did any error messages come up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you first attempt the `var e` is the index of the `document.getElementsByName(key+id)`

Try

```
for(var id in data){
    for(var key in data[id]){
        var elements = document.getElementsByName(key+id);
        for(var e in elements)
            var elem = elements[e];
            elem.innerHTML = data[id][key] !== null ? data[id][key] : "";
        }
```

Comment: better to write `elem.innerHTML = data[id][key] || '';`

Comment: bad case using `for(var e in elements)`. console.log your `e` and you will find properties as well.

Comment: I know, but he wanted to work with the for(var x in array) method

Answer (score 8):

`document.getElementsByName(key+id)` returns an array. The syntax `for(var x in y)` iterates over names in an object/array. The names in an object are the keys, the names in an array is the index.

Hence, `e` in you last loop, will be 0, 1, 2, 3, length, ....

Answer (score 0):

In first example, you made 2 mistakes.

1. don't run `for .. in` for `arrays`. Because you will iterate not over indexes but over properties as well.
2. in your case, `e` isn't element but index. Than't why it doesn't work

Comment: I needed the "keys" inside the data array to be able to reconstruct the element name after getting it from a 2D php array. and `for ... in` was the only I found where I could get them

Comment: @Yemto: I see you're mixing up PHP and JavaScript terminology. Associative arrays in PHP are called objects in JavaScript (`{}`). When one refers to an array in JavaScript, they are usually talking about an indexed array (`['a', 'b', 'c']`).

Comment: for `array` (in your case it's `array like`) use `for ( ... ) {}`. For real arrays you can use `forEach`

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy I know, I'm self learned on both languages and there for don't know all terminology. All I know is that I pass a 2D array where it's called keys to javascript using json and ajax.